# image upload from url with php oop

Tags: php

i am using the code bellow to upload images to my wp directory.
I tried to modified the code so i can download images directly from the url but i didnt have any luck.

My code is bellow:

```
<?php 

class imgUploader 
{ 
    var $exts = array( ".png", ".gif", ".png", ".jpg", ".jpeg" ); //all the extensions that will be allowed to be uploaded 
    var $maxSize = 9999999; //if you set to "0" (no quotes), there will be no limit 
    var $uploadTarget = "../wp-content/uploads/"; //make sure you have the '/' at the end 
    var $fileName = ""; //this will be automatically set. you do not need to worry about this 
    var $tmpName = ""; //this will be automatically set. you do not need to worry about this 

    public function startUpload() 
    { 
        $this->fileName = $_FILES['uploaded']['name']; 
        $this->tmpName = $_FILES['uploaded']['tmp_name']; 
        if( !$this->isWritable() ) 
        { 
            die( "Sorry, you must CHMOD your upload target to 777!" ); 
        } 
        if( !$this->checkExt() ) 
        { 
            die( "Sorry, you can not upload this filetype!" ); 
        } 
        if( !$this->checkSize() ) 
        { 
            die( "Sorry, the file you have attempted to upload is too large!" ); 
        } 
        if( $this->fileExists() ) 
        { 
            die( "Sorry, this file already exists on our servers!" ); 
        } 
        if( $this->uploadIt() ) 
        { 
            echo "Your file has been uploaded!<br><br>Click <a href=\"" . $this->uploadTarget . time() . $this->fileName . "\">here</a> to view your file!"; 
        } 
        else 
        { 
            echo "Sorry, your file could not be uploaded for some unknown reason!"; 
        } 
    } 

    public function uploadIt() 
    { 
        return ( move_uploaded_file( $this->tmpName, $this->uploadTarget . time() . $this->fileName ) ? true : false ); 
    } 

    public function checkSize() 
    { 
        return ( ( filesize( $this->tmpName ) > $this->maxSize ) ? false : true ); 
    } 

    public function getExt() 
    { 
        return strtolower( substr( $this->fileName, strpos( $this->fileName, "." ), strlen( $this->fileName ) - 1 ) ); 
    } 

    public function checkExt() 
    { 
        return ( in_array( $this->getExt(), $this->exts ) ? true : false ); 
    } 

    public function isWritable() 
    { 
        return ( is_writable( $this->uploadTarget ) ); 
    } 

    public function fileExists() 
    { 
        return ( file_exists( $this->uploadTarget . time() . $this->fileName ) ); 
    } 
} 
$img = new imgUploader(); 



if( $_POST['upload_file'] ) 
{ 
    $img->startUpload(); 
} 
else 
{ 
    echo "<form method=\"post\" enctype=\"multipart/form-data\"> 
        <p> 
            <label for=\"file\">Select a file to upload:</label> <input type=\"file\" name=\"uploaded\" id=\"file\"><br> 
            <input type=\"submit\" name=\"upload_file\" value=\"Upload!\"> 
        <p> 
    </form>"; 
} 
?>
```

I tried to remove the hole form and give to $filename and $temp name the image url but it doesnt work..

any idea?

Comment: totally different approach required, don't modify the above lean a little

Comment: @Dagon i think i must use curl right?

Comment: curl or file_get_contents

Comment: `die()` should be replaced by throwing Exception.